# How to use AutoScrollLabel in UILabel inside inputAccessoryView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, inputaccessoryview

How to use AutoScrollLabel in UILabel inside inputAccessoryView when the keyboard appears. I seem to have difficulties using it because I don't use an IB method to connect it to the code. I do this programatically. I have imported the .h file of AutoScrollView and it gives me errors.
[Find the AutoScrollLabel here](https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel)

This is my code for the inputAccessoryView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake
(0, 0, 320, 23)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
label.text = @"24 Hour time format only!";
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *text2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];

UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:text2, nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Can you show your error log?

Comment: If you go on the GitHub link above you will see the usage section. I tried using that and replacing it with the autoscrolllabel.whatever and i can't run the simulator because is says it doesn't recognise the autoscrolllabel.whatever. It is weird because I have imported the autoscrolllabel.h in my .m. And i have copied the two autoscrolllabel files to my project.

Comment: I have tried with `AutoScrollLabelDemo` by adding text field to it. It works fine for me? I've added `inputAccessoryView` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and set as nil in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. Try once again. It you want that code, i'll post it.

Comment: @Mani could you please show me your code if thats alright. Sorry but I'm a beginner. All of this is done programatically. No IB for the AutoscrollLabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example, I've created label with xib, then I add it into keyboard acc when it's appear.

Declare label like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScrollLabel;
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
self.autoScrollLabel.text = @"This text may be clipped, but now it will be scrolled. This text will be scrolled even after device rotation.";
    self.autoScrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.autoScrollLabel.labelSpacing = 35; // distance between start and end labels
    self.autoScrollLabel.pauseInterval = 1.7; // seconds of pause before scrolling starts again
    self.autoScrollLabel.scrollSpeed = 30; // pixels per second
    self.autoScrollLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; // centers text when no auto-scrolling is applied
    self.autoScrollLabel.fadeLength = 12.f;
    self.autoScrollLabel.scrollDirection = CBAutoScrollDirectionLeft;
    [self.autoScrollLabel observeApplicationNotifications];
```

Then,add code to textfield delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` as below

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.inputAccessoryView = self.autoScrollLabel;
}
```

And finally, add code to `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` as below

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.inputAccessoryView = nil;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting " Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union". What is this.

Comment: In which line, you got this? I think, you did mistake in somewhere else? Post your code which lead to this error.. put break point and track your error code..

Comment: All of the stuff in the view did load gives me that error. The "self.autoScrollLabel." is underlined in all of them.

Comment: Im not using XIB either. Just a storyboard.

Comment: What is there to connect?

Comment: what is there to connect. As mentioned before the label is done programmatically.

Comment: Sorry. I've missed that line. Why do you use ToolBar to show this label? If you show this label alone, don't need to add tool bar?

Comment: So your saying to get of the toolbar code completely. If so. How do I get the same toolbar look if I take it out and implement the label.

Comment: You can make it by adding background color and set corner radius. It could be possible. I didn't try with toolbar that's why I suggest this. If you can, try with toolbar.

Comment: I havee tried with toolbar by replacing the unlabel with the code you posted. Then it gave that error mentioned before. I will try with out toolbar.

Comment: I am now able to run the simulator but the inputAccessoryView doesn't appear.

Comment: Did you check whether you textfield delegate called or not?

Comment: In my header I have "<UITextFieldDelegate>" The key bored works but no label.

Comment: `textField.delegate = self`. did you set this? put break point on delegate method or log some text in delegate method..

Comment: Yes, still nothing appears.

Comment: Do I need to do anything in my storyboard? Also after placing breakpoints on the - textFieldDidFinish and did begin editing it said that the textfield became first responder, which is what i want it to do.

Comment: No. No. You have created label by programmatically. I'm asked to check whether label is nil or not in delegate methods.. because it's created in viewdidLoad. If you created as weak property, it will be nil in delegate method. If you didn't assign it to your property, it will be nil in delegate method. that's y, asking to show your code.

Comment: So how can I fix it. Thank you for your help so far @Mani.

Comment: You have to create strong property to hold create label in ViewDidload  as `self.yourLabel = createdLabel`. and set accview in didbegin delegate method as `textField.inputAccessoryView = self.yourLabel`

Comment: What is createdLabel.

Comment: hey man, show your code. I mean createdLabel by label which is created inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: Inside my view did load I placed the autoScrollLabel.

Comment: did you mean `self.autoScrollLabel = label`. ?  label means `UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake
(0, 0, 320, 23)];` Am I right?

Comment: If I do that it says "incompatible pointer types assigning to CBAutoScrollLabel.

Comment: did you try this? `CBAutoScrollLabel *label = [[CBAutoScrollLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 23)];`

Comment: It doesn't scroll @Mani

Answer (score 0):

I to have had the text not scroll when I think it should. What I have discovered is that if the width of the label that displays the text is larger than the text to display it will not scroll. This bring up the issue where the displayed text is now truncated with "..."  It scrolls, but it only shows the text up to and including the "..."  If you change the font size to a smaller size, it works as expected, is this by design, I do not know. Other than those 2 issues, this is a very nice feature.